# Linking to anchors does not go to exact location?

Tags: css, anchor

I have 5 taps in a `<div>` with this style:

```
foo { 
   width: 781px;
   height: 1000px;
   float: left;
   position: relative;
   top: 90px;
   left: 50px;
   padding-right: 20px; 
   right: 30px;
   background-color: #ffc;
}
```

I navigate to this taps from menu, when I click in menu it should go down in exact taps and its go down but far away not in the exact taps, and when I change the height in the CCS above to 750px form 1000px everything be OK but I don't want to change the height.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'taps'. 'Tabs'?

Comment: Please take a few minutes to add some HTML.  Your question is out of context, so without the details, it is hard to give you an answer.  Also, "taps" means what, click on a link? or "tags" ??

Comment: make a fiddle of your code to get a better idea